# Google Calendar event id, not icalUID

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a script to retrieve certain events from my calendar and send an email for each qualifying event with a hyperlink to the event. For that I need event id, not icalUID. How do I get that? Here is my code (actual IDs and names were removed):

```js
function GetFamilyEvents () {
  //Gets all events that start/end/or span within next 30 days
  var FamilyCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("someID@group.calendar.google.com");
  var CurrentDate = new Date(); //Gets current date
  var RangeEnd = new Date(CurrentDate.getTime() + 720 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //Adds 30 days in milliseconds to the current date
  var FamilyEvents = FamilyCalendar.getEvents(CurrentDate,RangeEnd); //returns events that start, end, or encompass wihtin 30 days starting from today; Time range is Current Date to Range End
  

  for(var i = 0; i<FamilyEvents.length; i++){
    var EventTitle = FamilyEvents[i].getTitle();
    var EventCreatedDate = FamilyEvents[i].getDateCreated();
    var EventStartDate = FamilyEvents[i].getStartTime();
    var EventEndDate = FamilyEvents[i].getEndTime();
    var EventCreator = FamilyEvents[i].getCreators(); //Gets the creator of the event to email notificaiton to
    var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getID();
    var CalendarID = FamilyCalendar.getId();
    

    //Check if an event was created today AND does not have our names or "FYI" in its title
    if(EventCreatedDate.valueOf() <= CurrentDate.valueOf() && EventTitle.indexOf('Name1')<0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name2')<0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name3')<0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name4')<0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name5')<0 && EventTitle.indexOf('FYI')<0) 
      {
        //Creates variables for the HTML body of the email notification. The same variables are referenced in the body of the HTML template.
        var EmailMessage = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("EmailMessage"); //"EmailMessage" is the name of the HTML file in this script.
            EmailMessage.recepient = EventCreator;
            EmailMessage.eventTitle = EventTitle;
            EmailMessage.eventStartDate = EventStartDate;
            EmailMessage.eventEndDate = EventEndDate;
            EmailMessage.calendarID = CalendarID;
            EmailMessage.eventID = EventID;
      };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `For that I need event id, not icalUID.`, when you want to retrieve the event ID, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getID();
```

#### To:

```
var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getId().split("@")[0];
```

- `Id` of `getId()` is required to be modifieid.
- `getId()` returns the value like `###@google.com` which is iCalUID. The event ID is retrieved from this as `###`.

#### Reference:

- [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getid)

### Added:

From your replying,

> what I meant was that my original code and your modifications give the same result: 2C18CFDB-E6B6-4653-AB65-21C990969103 - this is what I get for both options.

In this case, how about using Calendar API? By this, both the event ID and also the hyperlink of the event can be retrieved. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set your calendar ID.

```js
function sample() {
  var calendarId = "someID@group.calendar.google.com"; // Please set your calendar ID

  //Gets all events that start/end/or span within next 30 days
  var CurrentDate = new Date(); //Gets current date
  var RangeEnd = new Date(CurrentDate.getTime() + 720 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //Adds 30 days in milliseconds to the current date

  var items = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, { timeMin: CurrentDate.toISOString(), timeMax: RangeEnd.toISOString(), maxResults: 2500 }).items;
  items.forEach(e => {
    var EventTitle = e.summary; // FamilyEvents[i].getTitle();
    var EventCreatedDate = new Date(e.created); // FamilyEvents[i].getDateCreated();
    var EventStartDate = new Date(e.start.dateTime || e.start.date);// FamilyEvents[i].getStartTime();
    var EventEndDate = new Date(e.end.dateTime || e.end.date); // FamilyEvents[i].getEndTime();
    var EventCreator = e.creator.email; // FamilyEvents[i].getCreators(); //Gets the creator of the event to email notificaiton to
    var EventID = e.id; // FamilyEvents[i].getID();
    var CalendarID = calendarId; // FamilyCalendar.getId();

    var eventUrl = e.htmlLink; // If you want to retrieve the hyperlink of the event, you can use this.

    //Check if an event was created today AND does not have our names or "FYI" in its title
    if (EventCreatedDate.valueOf() <= CurrentDate.valueOf() && EventTitle.indexOf('Name1') < 0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name2') < 0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name3') < 0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name4') < 0 && EventTitle.indexOf('Name5') < 0 && EventTitle.indexOf('FYI') < 0) {
      //Creates variables for the HTML body of the email notification. The same variables are referenced in the body of the HTML template.
      var EmailMessage = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("EmailMessage"); //"EmailMessage" is the name of the HTML file in this script.
      EmailMessage.recepient = EventCreator;
      EmailMessage.eventTitle = EventTitle;
      EmailMessage.eventStartDate = EventStartDate;
      EmailMessage.eventEndDate = EventEndDate;
      EmailMessage.calendarID = CalendarID;
      EmailMessage.eventID = EventID;
      
      // do something

    };
  });


}
```

- In this sample script, `eventUrl` is the hyperlink of the event.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Tanaike. The result of the code you suggest is the same as `getID()`:

`var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getID();` = `2C18CFDB-E6B6-4653-AB65-21C990969103`


`var EventID2 = FamilyEvents[i].getId().split("@")[0];` = `2C18CFDB-E6B6-4653-AB65-21C990969103`

It doesn't get the `id` of an event... Thanks anyway

Comment: @7ka2 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your replying, I think that `var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getID();` is required to be modified to `var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getId();`. So I cannot understand your showing values retrieved from `var EventID = FamilyEvents[i].getID();`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: Hi, what I meant was that my original code and your modifications give the same result: 2C18CFDB-E6B6-4653-AB65-21C990969103 - this is what I get for both options.

Comment: @7ka2 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I thought that when Calendar API is used for your situation, it might be suitable. So I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Thank you @tanaike! Using advanced calendar API worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: @7ka2 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Event ID can be determined if you have both the `iCalUID` and the corresponding `CalendarID` that event belongs to. And once you have the Event ID, assembling a URL for the event is a piece of cake.

**Step 1**
Grab the first part of the iCalUID.. up to but not including the @ sign.

**Step 2**
Concatenate the string from step 1 with a the CalendarID separated by a single space.

**Step 3**
Use the built-in [Utilities class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodewebsafedata,-charset) to encode the string from step 2 to a web-safe base64 string.

**Step 4**
Assemble your url

```
let str = EventID.split('@')[0].toString();
let str2 = str + ' ' + CalendarID;
let eid = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(str2, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
let url = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=' + eid;
```

We can simplify all that into a one liner. Add it to your `for` loop after the CalendarID variable declaration.

```
let url = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=' + Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(EventID.split('@')[0].toString() + ' ' + CalendarID, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Hi @Jahnis, thanks for the suggestion. It does give me what the ID of an event would look like. However, when I try to use the resulted ink to navigate to an event, Calendar complaints that it couldn't find the even (it does exist). Any ideas what troubleshooting steps I could take? Thank you